# Button Onclick to another react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I want to know that how to return Log component when button clicks I invoked function but its not invoking properly as I got to know that from one of the stackoverflow that onclick event invokes by using react hooks but I want to invoke function in that I am calling login component

```js
import React from "react";
import { Navbar, Nav, Container, Button } from "react-bootstrap";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { HashLink as Link } from "react-router-hash-link";
import "bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js";
import "./Header.css";
import Frontline from "../Frontline";
import Infoline from "../Infoline";
import Workline from "../Workline";
import Helpline from "../Helpline";
import Log from "../login";
// import Footer from '../Footer/Footer'

export default function Header() {
  const onButtonClick = () => {
    return <Log />;
  };

  return (
    <div className="Navbar">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Navbar
          bg="dark"
          variant="dark"
          sticky="top"
          expand="lg"
          collapseOnSelect
        >
          <Button
            className="d-none d-sm-block d-md-block d-lg-none"
            onClick={onButtonClick()}
          >
            Login
          </Button>
        </Navbar>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: For the second approach, you may use useNavigate() hook to navigate or show your Log component.

Comment: What do you mean by _how to return Log component when button clicks_ do you mean navigating to the Log component? Do you have a `BrowserRouter` component in your `App` component? Why is there a `BrowserRouter` in your header?

Comment: Are you wanting to ***navigate*** to a route rendering the `Log` component in response to clicking the button? Returning JSX from asynchronously called callbacks doesn't render anything to the DOM. Can you [edit] to provide more details what exactly it is you are trying to do, and to include all relevant code in a [mcve]?

Answer (score 1):

One problem is that you are immediately invoking onButtonClick instead of passing in the function. Try to change it to this
`onClick={onButtonClick}`. But as others are pointing out this is not how you render JSX to the DOM. If you are trying to redirect the user to a Login page then you would need to setup a Route to your component. I would suggest reading up on the [React Router quick start for some examples and to get a deeper understanding of how routing works](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start). Remember to check the documentation for your version of `react-router`

Comment: That is *a* problem.... it's not ***THE*** problem.

Comment: My bad, of course you are right. I will uppdate my answer